# Is it possible to have only the router-outlet as main component?

Tags: angular

Currently I'm using this construction to get my router-outlet working as the main app:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-dummy-app',
    template: '<router-outlet></router-outlet>'
})

export class MyDummyApp {
}
```

Is it possible to cut out the dummy app? I've not had any success. I've tried leaving `bootstrap` empty, or keep my router-components in the `entry` collection, but no module config seems to work.

Angular seems bent on having a main component to bootstrap.

Comment: what will be in your index.html?

Comment: <router-outlet></router-outlet>

Comment: So what happens if you try to bootstrap to `RouterOutlet`, which should be exported from `@angular/router`? Presumably any selectors from directives and components included in the `boostrap` array of your "Root Module" are going to be matched and mounted from `index.html`. It either works or throws an error. AFAIK 'router-outlet' is just another directive.

Comment: @NeilLunn hehe: "Uncaught Error: RouterOutlet cannot be used as an entry component.". That's too bad!

Comment: More or less answers the question then. And the specific error means that is quite intentional. So I would just accept it for what it is.

Comment: Just found this quote in the [NgModule FAQ](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/ngmodule-faq.html):
> "You can embed the child components in the top component's template. Alternatively, make the top component a routing host by giving it a <router-outlet>. Define child routes and let the router load module components into that outlet."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally you would bootstrap the AppComponent, whos template is anything + `<router-outlet>` in some place, in the AppModule. Afterwards you would initialize the AppModule as entry point.

Without a main component as entry point I cant imagine how could you tell angular what should be the entry point of the application.

I would say its not possible. When you declare a component in bootstrap in the AppModule, angular will look for its css selector in index.html. If not found -> error. In the other hand, if you dont declare anything inside of the bootstrap section in your app module -> error. Furthermore, if you try to bootstrap the RouterOutet directive in your app module

> `Uncaught Error: RouterOutlet cannot be used as an entry component.`

Also the following quote from the [NgModule FAQ](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/ngmodule-faq.html) seems to support this:

> You can embed the child components in the top component's template. Alternatively, make the top component a routing host by giving it a `<router-outlet>`. Define child routes and let the router load module components into that outlet.

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to achieve a similar thing and was redirected to this thread. What I wanted is to render a component (say, Component1) as default. Then, based on few interactions in Component1, I wanted to **replace** Component1 with a different component (say, Component2).

**Solution**: Configure default route to Component1, use [routerLink] in Component1 to redirect to Component2.
In app.component.html include only `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` and nothing else.

**Reason**: An HTML page **must** have html, head, and body tags to render, which is included in index.html. Then, you have a selector to `<app-root>` where you display your `<router-outlet>`.