# Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find primary outlet to load 'AppComponent'

Tags: angular, routes, angular2-routing

I changed my routes so that my homepage is the appcomponent, and now I'm getting this error:

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find primary outlet to load 'AppComponent'
```

Any thoughts as to what this could be?

My routes:

```
import {Routes} from "@angular/router";
import {PatientComponent} from "./patient/patient.component";
import {AppComponent} from "./app.component";



export const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', component: AppComponent},
  {path: 'patient/:id', component: PatientComponent},

];
```

my app component:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {AfdelingService} from './afdeling.service';
import {PatientService} from './patient.service';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import {Router} from "@angular/router";


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  providers: [AfdelingService, PatientService]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  errorMessage: string;
  afdeling = [];

  constructor(private afdelingService: AfdelingService, private router: Router) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getData()
  }

  goToAfdeling(afdeling) {
    console.log(afdeling.afdelingsNaam);
    this.router.navigate(["/afdelingen", afdeling.afdelingsNaam]);
  }

  getData() {
    this.afdelingService.getAfdelingen()
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          this.afdeling = data;
          console.log(this.afdeling);
        }, error => this.errorMessage = <any> error);


  }
}
```

Comment: Your app component should be your application shell and should not be a routing target.

Comment: adding to above comment... you need to define router-outlet to display the route content...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AppComponent` should **not** be a *routed component*. Instead, it should only be the entry point for your application. This means, that the template should at least contain the `router outlet` in some part of it, the css selector of app component should be in your index.html file and `AppComponent` should be declared inside of the `bootstrap` list of you `AppModule`.

See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44364581/is-it-possible-to-have-only-the-router-outlet-as-main-component/44364660#44364660) for more info